# Anchor and Chunk not working in iText 2.1.7

Tags: hyperlink, anchor, itext

All,

Good morning.

I was trying to create Links from one part of PDF document to other part using iText.
Version of iText I use is 2.1.7

I tried using both Anchors and Chunks and neither are working. Basically the link does not become Clickable at all.

Here is the Destination code with Anchor and Chunk:

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Reach here");
anchor.setName("DestinationID");
pdfDocument.add(anchor);

Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Reach here");
chunk.setLocalDestination("DestinationID");
pdfDocument.add(chunk);
```

Here is the Link code with Anchor and Chunk:

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Click Here", PDFConstants.HELVETICA_8_BOLD_UNDERLINE);
anchor.setReference("#DestinationID");
cell.add(anchor);

Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Click Here", PDFConstants.HELVETICA_8_BOLD_UNDERLINE);
chunk.setLocalGoto("DestinationID");
cell.add(chunk);
```

// cell gets added to a Table later

Appreciate if someone could point what I was doing wrong.

thank you,
Raghavan

Answer (score 1):

You have to take in account the Bruno Lowagie comments and upgrade your version because iText 2.1.7 is an old version an doesn't complain with new PDFReference specifications. 
Anywise I don't see anything wrong in your code snippet, may be the problem is in the rest of your code which you're not showing up. I did a simple test with Chunk with a 2.1.7 version an it worked, I give you my sample if you want to check if there is something that could help you:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.lowagie.text.Cell;
import com.lowagie.text.Chunk;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.Table;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PDFChunkTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, DocumentException {


        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/pdf.pdf"));

        doc.open();

        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("click here", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 255)));
        chunk.setLocalGoto("test");

        Table tab = new Table(1, 2);
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.add(chunk);
        tab.addCell(cell);
        doc.add(tab);

        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...");
        doc.add(p2);
        doc.add(p2);
        doc.add(p2);
        doc.add(p2);
        doc.add(p2);
        doc.add(p2);

        Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk("local destination", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        chunk2.setLocalDestination("test");
        doc.add(chunk2);

        doc.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response albciff. The PDF generation code I have is very complex and will not be worth posting it here. I could understand if by clicking the link it goes to where I don't intend. But the Chunk itself is not appearing as Clickable at all. I will compare the code you posted about adding cell to table and table to doc with mine and let you know if I could make it work. I am sure you are a developer who works in corporate world where decisions are not always in your hand but you are left with delivering something. Hopefully you and the author can understand my situation.

Comment: Hi, of course I understand your situation, I only made a recommendation :). Finally this code helps to solve your problem?